# JsPlumb Touch Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I have an application that use JsPlumb Framework. It works fine on a desktop, however when using an touch device it fails to work correctly.

I have an object that can be dragged around the screen, this works fine on both a touch device and desktop. However I have also got an action that when a user click on the device it can set a connector to drag a line to another object to join them together. However on the touch devices it fails to set the connector.

The touch device will draw an icon but it will display appear straight away. Is this before the touch device can't tell the difference between the drag/touch option.

I have added some code to see if it has something to do with my code.

```
$("#container").append(state)
jsPlumb.draggable("state" + i);

jsPlumb.makeSource($('.item'), {
   connector: 'StateMachine',
});
jsPlumb.makeTarget($('.item'), {
   anchor: 'Continuous',
   reattach:true,
   isTarget:true,
   beforeDrop:function(params) {
      'Some code'
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8jMqG/6/

**EDIT AGAIN**

From the docs the following is showed

*Tip: use the three-argument addEndpoint method for common data
One thing that happens quite often is that you have an Endpoint whose appearance and behaviour is largely the same between usages on different elements, with just a few differences.*

```
var exampleGreyEndpointOptions = {
   endpoint:"Rectangle",
   paintStyle:{ width:25, height:21, fillStyle:'#666' },
   isSource:true,
   connectorStyle : { strokeStyle:"#666" },
   isTarget:true
```

};

Which is what I'm doing on the jsfiddle.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

I have been using jsPlumb for some time now. My app works both on desktop & mobile. Of course, there's a difference between click & touch.

I use `jquery-ui-touchpunch` for mobile device support; clicking, dragging objects/connections & creating connections works smooth on mobile too.

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

**Update**

After creating the endpoints or making certain elements source & target, the next step is to join them for the connection to appear. Of course, if the sole-aim is to just connect, then you can skip creating endpoints/sources/targets & directly join them using

```
jsPlumb.connect({
    source:"element1", 
    target:"element2",
    anchors:["Right", "Left" ],
    endpoint:"Rectangle",
    endpointStyle:{ fillStyle: "yellow" }
});
```

[DOCS](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/connections.html#programmatic)

Currently, you're trying to make the same element(s) `.item` both source & target.
Also, you're trying to make the same elements source & target with every click (event). Why repeating it ?

[APIDOCS](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/jsPlumbInstance.html#makeTarget)

I guess there's some confusion in what you need and what the code says.

Comment: Doesn't work - I can drag the item around the screen, I just can't add an connector to the object.

Comment: it's strange, if it works in desktop then using `touchpunch` should get it working in mobile. Can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: I tried on firefox & chrome, but the fiddle didn't worked. Also, I noticed you just created source & target but never joined them!

Comment: I need the same element to be created every click on a menu item. So I have made it the same item to be created. The source and target doesn't need to be populated as they joined correctly. As any item can be connected to any item.

Comment: In the question you've mentioned - `However I have also got an action that when a user click on the device it can set a connector to drag a line to another object to join them together. However on the touch devices it fails to set the connector. ` - Show associated code. The current code only creates elements and don't join them.